# Strange accounts are created within an application in development mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know the question is not about programming, but I'm a bit confused

I work on the Android app and have not published or shared it with anyone and there is no other app related to the app or databases

Despite that, I find accounts that I haven't added to databases, there are people who create accounts in databases in some way.
How can I find out how they can create an account?

These are some of the accounts who created my account :

```
admin@sheridanbuilding.com.au
megaliceb@aol.com
lcchen93@hotmail.com
headphonejackbuisness@gmail.com
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Once an account is created, there is no way to track how that happened.  The APIs for dealing with Firebase Auth are effectively public, so once you enable the email/password authentication method, anyone can start using it, even outside of your app.

Comment: Do I have to do something or neglect it!

Comment: You can delete the accounts if you want.  You have no obligation to do anything.